# Having en-dash at the end of the string doesn't allow json_encode

Tags: php, json, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

I am trying to extract n characters from a string using
`substr($originalText,0,250)`;

The nth character is an en-dash. So I get the last character as â€ when I view it in notepad. In my editor, Brackets, I can't even open the log file it since it only supports UTF-8 encoding.

I also cannot run json_encode on this string.

However, when I use `substr($originalText,0,251)`, it works just fine. I can open the log file and it shows an en-dash instead of â€. json_encode also works fine.

I can use `mb_convert_encoding($mystring, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252")` to circumvent the problem, but could anyone tell me why having these characters at the end specifically causes an error?
Moreover, on doing this, my log file shows â€ in brackets, which is confusing too.

My question is why is having the en-dash at the end of the string, different from having it anywhere else (followed by other characters).

Hopefully my question is clear, if not I can try to explain further.

Thanks.

Comment: `substr()` isn't the best function to use for working with multibyte charset strings, look at `mb_substr()` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) uses so-called surrogates which extend the codepage beyond ASCII to accomodate many more characters.

A single UTF-8 character may be coded into one, two, three or four bytes, depending on the character.

You cut the string right in the middle of a multi-byte character:

```
[<-character->]
[byte-0|byte-1]
       ^
      You cut the string right here in the middle!


[<-----character---->]
[byte-0|byte-1|byte-2]
       ^      ^
      Or anywhere here if it's 3 bytes long.
```

So the decoder has the first byte(s) but can't read the entire character because the string ends prematurely.

This causes all the effects you are witnessing.

The solution to this problem is [here in Dezza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044399/3227403).

Comment: I thought it might be something like that because changing the limit from 250 to 249 only prints â. Thanks for explaining it well though.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it explains what was going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I tried to explain the problem. The solution is the multibyte version `mb_substr()` as shown in the other answer. I always think that understanding a problem is more important than applying blindly a solution.

Answer (score 5):

[Pid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044470/3761174) gives an explanation for why this is happening, this answer just looks at what you can do about it...

## Use mb_substr()

The [multibyte string](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) module was designed for exactly this situation, and provides a number of string functions that handle multibyte characters correctly. I suggest having a look through there as there are likely other ones that you will need in other places of your application.

You may need to install or enable this module if you get a function not found error. Instructions for this are platform dependent and out-of-scope for this question.

The function you want for the case in your question is called [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and is called the same as you would use `substr()`, but has other optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Using mb_substr() works better than mb_convert_encoding(). I don't have to re-encode it on my front end now.